# Keyword coupled with a function in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, menu

I have created a menu system for my program. I have the functions saved in another file that I haven't referenced here.

Here is my code:

```
print("\nHauptmenü\n")
hauptmenue = {"Information":programm_information,
              "Beenden": programm_beenden,
              "Hilfe":programm_erklaerung,
              "Trennzeichen":text_trennzeichen,
              "Lesen":csv_suchanfrage,
              "csv_suche":csv_suchanfrage}
while True:
    for menue_punkt in enumerate (hauptmenue):
        print(menue_punkt)
    eingabe = input("\nOption: bitte einen Menüpunkt eingeben: ")
    args = eingabe.split()
    if len(args) < 4:
        if args[0] in hauptmenue:
            key = args[0]
            hauptmenue[key]()
        else:
            print (eingabe," ist keine gültige Option.\n ")
            print("Hauptmenü\n")
```

output:

```
Hauptmenü

(0, 'Information')
(1, 'Beenden')
(2, 'Hilfe')
(3, 'Trennzeichen')
(4, 'Lesen')
(5, 'csv_suche')

Option: bitte einen Menüpunkt eingeben: Information
Version : 1.0
Datum der letzten Version : 04.01.2020
(0, 'Information')
(1, 'Beenden')
(2, 'Hilfe')
(3, 'Trennzeichen')
(4, 'Lesen')
(5, 'csv_suche')

Option: bitte einen Menüpunkt eingeben:
```

So, the program does everything that I want it to do, but the problem is that it is a bit cumbersome for me. If I want to access "Information", I have to to enter "Information" and I can't deviate from that because the system won't recognize the entry.

I want to make it so that it can recognize "0" or "Information"; a fuzzy match of the user's entry as a proper entry would be better.

Any suggestions on how I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing complicated things, we can use a dictionary with input-numbers and functions. That is:

```
hauptmenue = {"Information":programm_information,
              "Beenden": programm_beenden,
              "Hilfe":programm_erklaerung,
              "Trennzeichen":text_trennzeichen,
              "Lesen":csv_suchanfrage,
              "csv_suche":csv_suchanfrage}
inputmenu = {0 : "Information",
             1 : "Beenden",
             2 : "Hilfe",
             3 : "Trennzeichen",
             4 : "Lesen",
             5 : "csv_suche"}
while True:
    for choice, option in enumerate(inputmenu):
        print(choice, option)
    choice_str = input("\nOption: bitte einen Menüpunkt eingeben: ").strip() # strip removes leading n trailing white spaces.
    if choice_str.isalpha():
        #Everything is alphabet, so it must an option name.
        option = choice_str #Not needed, but writing to make it easy to understand
    else:
        option = inputmenu.get(int(choice_str), None) # gives None if choice not found.
    func = hauptmenue.get(option, False)
    if not func: func()
```

This is quick and better for small set of inputs and easy to maintain.
You can make it more user-friendly by using lower-case letters in hauptmenu and conveting input of user to lowercase.

Comment: Ah, okay, I am still kind of learning. So, I tend to overthink thinks and make them more complicated than necessary. I really appreciate your answer and it helps me out a lot.

Comment: Thanks for that. Overthinking is a basic thing in programming. But remember to be strict in some-cases, that is, don't make your program a much complicated one in name of making it easier to use.

Comment: Something not related tho, are you German? I think, making code in English is better when posting it online for help. Like, take myself, I'm a Tamilian and your program was a bit hard for me to read.

Comment: Hey, no, I'm not German, but German is my second language. So, I'm writing the program in German (it's a personal program that I am not necessarily intending to distribute. That's why I prefer to write it in German.) You're right though. I was a bit lazy and just assumed that the program's syntax would explain the function of the program. I'll be sure to post in English next time.

Comment: I suggested an edit, let me know what you think! The line `option = inputmenu.get(int(choice_str), "NONE")` is entirely your own creation, right, it doesn't come from OP? If that is the case, why use a string to indicate `None`?

Comment: Also @PoetryLion do bear in mind that this code does not really validate input eh, it can easily throw an error.

Comment: @AMC sorry for late reply. That was part of my previous code which I edited and forgot to remove that one..

Comment: And @AMC, I wanted this to be an easy and dirty fix for normal situation, as I felt like adding error handling would confuse the OP easily. That's why. I like your solution too, upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a decent solution, which includes input verification. You could easily make this into a generic function.

```py
def programm_information():
    return None


def programm_beenden():
    return None


def programm_erklaerung():
    return None


def text_trennzeichen():
    return None


def csv_suchanfrage():
    return None


menu_options_dict = {"Information": programm_information,
                     "Beenden": programm_beenden,
                     "Hilfe": programm_erklaerung,
                     "Trennzeichen": text_trennzeichen,
                     "Lesen": csv_suchanfrage,
                     "csv_suche": csv_suchanfrage}

invalid_input_msg = 'Invalid choice, please try again. Press ENTER to continue.'

while True:
    print('Choose an option:')
    for num, elem in enumerate(menu_options_dict, start=1):
        print(f'{num}: {elem}')
    choice_str = input('Option: bitte einen Menüpunkt eingeben: ').strip()
    options_dict_res = menu_options_dict.get(choice_str)
    if options_dict_res:
        break
    else:
        try:
            choice_num = int(choice_str)
        except ValueError:
            input(invalid_input_msg)
        else:
            if 0 < choice_num <= len(menu_options_dict):
                options_dict_res = list(menu_options_dict.values())[choice_num - 1]
                break
            else:
                input(invalid_input_msg)

print(options_dict_res)
func_res = options_dict_res()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. I learned a couple new things from it ! I didn't know about the "start=1" function However, I am still having trouble it accepting strings and integers as valid entries. For example, 1 and "Information" should have the same value in that they lead to the same result. Unfortunately, the program only still accepts an integer and not a string.

Comment: @PoetryLion That’s bizarre, I thought I had tested it. None of the words works?

Comment: @PoetryLion Never mind, there was indeed an issue! I made quick fix, see the edit.

Comment: Hey, it functions perfectly and does everything that I need! Thanks a bunch.